# C# - creating groups of points

Tags: c#, coordinates, cluster-analysis, point

How to create something that accepts one point and list of all points and returns list of points that are close enough to the original point or to the point which is close enough.

If you still can't understand me here's a picture:

[image: Point grouping]

I've tried:

```
    int range = 6;
    public List<IntPoint> getClosePoints(ref Dictionary<IntPoint,bool> allPoints,IntPoint startingPoint) {
        List<IntPoint> closePoints = new List<IntPoint>();
        closePoints.Add(startingPoint);
        bool gotBigger = true;

        while (gotBigger) {
            gotBigger = false;
            foreach (IntPoint proven in closePoints.ToList()) {
                foreach (IntPoint possible in allPoints.Keys.ToList()) {
                    if (isInRange(proven,possible,range) && !allPoints[possible]) {
                        gotBigger = true;
                        closePoints.Add(possible);
                        allPoints[possible] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return closePoints;
    }

    public bool isInRange(IntPoint A, IntPoint B, int range){
        if(A.DistanceTo(B) < range)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

(`IntPoint` is similiar to `Point`, it is from `AForge`, all points have `bool` value false)
But this makes my program super-laggy considering that it is called thousand times a loop. :/ (And also it doesn't seem to work now)

Comment: Show *something* you have tried.

Comment: @sbouaked They just have to be in range, of 2 units. Doesn't matter how far are they when they are in that range.

Comment: OMG... my eyes......

Comment: do you have any memory constraints, I can think of a quick CPU-efficient solution, but it would require a lot of Memory to work. By expanding the Points list to a int[,] array some island counting like algorithm could be applied

Comment: @Luiso why did you delete your previous answer?

Comment: @Luiso How much memory?

Comment: @Valli3 Consider using a broadphase to reduce the number of points you have to check against. Two common types are quad trees and spatial hashing.

Comment: @HighCore it only returned the points within distance of the original points

Comment: So you are reinventing DBSCAN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
public IEnumerable<Point> GetPoints(Point origin, IEnumerable<Point> points, int distance)
{
    var result = new HashSet<Point>();
    var found = new Queue<Point>();
    found.Enqueue(origin)

    while(found.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = found.Dequeue();
        var candidates = points
            .Where(p => !result.Contains(p) &&
                   p.Distance(current) <= distance);

        foreach(var p in candidates)
        {
            result.Add(p);
            found.Enqueue(p)
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

i think this is straight forward enough, in any case the HashSet feature is that it can tell if it contains an item in near O(1).

Answer (score 2):

This is a clustering problem. In simple steps,

1. Get all the points close to your input points;
2. Add all the points to, maybe, a Hashset;
3. Now put all the points in your Hashset into a queue and goto step 1.
4. Break when your Hashset is same as previous iteration. You have found all the right points.